# Android assets : SQLiteDatabase Missing databases/***.zip file in assets or target folder not writable

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-sqlite

There are lots of open threads on Stackoverflow ( Went through all but non of thread gave me correct answer to solve this problem).

Got this error on various OS 2.3.6, 4.0.3 ( So definitely not related to Android OS Version )

**Scenario 1 :** Application Version 2.0 is available in market for users to download

**STEP 1 -** User downloads application and **no errors**.

**Scenario 2 :** Application Version 2.0 is available in market for users to download

**STEP 1 -** User already has previous version of application 1.5 ( Market asks user to update and user performs update ). Market uninstalls and installs new version and system crashes on start of application with below error..

```
I/Database(31396): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at line 27205 of [42537b6056]

E/Database(31396): sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.XXXXX.XXXXX/databases/XXX", &handle, 2, NULL) failed

W/b       (31396): could not open database XXX - unable to open database file

W/b       (31396): copying database from assets...

W/b       (31396): extracting file: 'XXX'...

E/b       (31396): Couldn't open XXX for writing (will try read-only):

E/b       (31396): com.a.a.a: Missing databases/XXX.zip file in assets or target folder not writable

E/b       (31396):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(Native Method)

E/b       (31396):  at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.open(BlockGuard.java:232)

E/b       (31396):  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:94)

E/b       (31396):  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:165)

E/b       (31396):  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:144)

E/b       (31396):  at com.a.a.b.b(Unknown Source)

E/b       (31396):  at com.a.a.b.a(Unknown Source)

E/b       (31396):  at com.a.a.b.getWritableDatabase(Unknown Source)

E/b       (31396):  at com.a.a.b.getReadableDatabase(Unknown Source)

E/b       (31396):  at com.XXXXX.XXXXX.x.a(Unknown Source)

E/b       (31396):  at com.XXXXX.XXXXX.ay.a(Unknown Source)

E/b       (31396):  at com.XXXXX.XXXXX.ay.doInBackground(Unknown Source)

E/b       (31396):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)

E/b       (31396):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)

E/b       (31396):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)

E/b       (31396):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)

E/b       (31396):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)

E/b       (31396):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

I/Database(31396): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at line 27205 of [42537b6056]

E/Database(31396): sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.XXXXX.XXXXX/databases/XXX", &handle, 1, NULL) failed

W/System.err(31396): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file

W/System.err(31396):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)

W/System.err(31396):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1857)

W/System.err(31396):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:824)

W/System.err(31396):    at com.a.a.b.getReadableDatabase(Unknown Source)

W/System.err(31396):    at com.XXXXX.XXXXX.x.a(Unknown Source)

W/System.err(31396):    at com.XXXXX.XXXXX.ay.a(Unknown Source)

W/System.err(31396):    at com.XXXXX.XXXXX.ay.doInBackground(Unknown Source)

W/System.err(31396):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)

W/System.err(31396):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)

W/System.err(31396):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)

W/System.err(31396):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)

W/System.err(31396):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)

W/System.err(31396):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

**Scenario 3 :** Application Version 2.0 is available in market for users to download

**STEP 1 -** User already has previous version of application 1.5 ( Uninstalls application by himself and manully goes to market and installs application. **NO ERROR**

I'm puzzled why exception is thrown at Scenario 2. Does upgrade works differently compare to install and uninstall and why it says target folder not writable

Comment: Is new database file name different?
Are you sure that, your code is closing all I/O handling variables? in sequence ...
1. check database .. close IO
2. Yes .. no worries
3. No - copy from assets close IO
4. repeat 1

Comment: @NikhilPingle - Yes they are closed, if that was the case it should fail in Scenario 1 & 3 as well.. It works perfectly fine

Comment: We analyzed further and came to conclusion that this happened because one of developer updated sharedUserId in Manifest file..  Lesson learned ---- DO NOT update sharedUserId for already released application..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We analyzed further and came to conclusion that this happened because one of developer updated sharedUserId in Manifest file.. Lesson learned ----

**DO NOT update sharedUserId** for already released application.